# C# events vs loop

Tags: c#, .net, events

Having a hard time understanding how events truly work.

Say i have a loop that checks to see if i have pressed the letter 'a' on my keyboard every millisecond.
How is that different from an event with the same set up, doesn't it have to do a check all the time to see if i have pressed the key in order to trigger the event?
It must have to pay attention all the time causing overhead just like a loop right? or is it dormant which makes no since to me how it gets triggered without constantly checking.

Comment: The answer depends on the specific technology you're dealing with. In Windows Forms (for example) I have high confidence that the native Windows message processing loop is far more efficient than any manual loop you could write.

Comment: Especially if its able to trap the key press interrupt so that its not polling at all (which it likely is). Don't do this manually!

Comment: The underlying operating system already has ways (polling/interrupts) for catching input, and it will dispatch events to the appropriate application window. You don't need to reimplement polling yourself.

Comment: Best let the OS handle this.

Comment: Events are a mechanism for propagating information about... an event. Whether that event was detected by polling or by some other method (e.g. hardware interrupt, physics engine collision detection code, etc.) is completely orthogonal.

Comment: Even if interrupts didn't exist, compare the cost of the OS polling and sending keypresses to the active application, vs every running application polling.

Comment: In the olden days of assembly programming one notices that when the CPU sees an interrupt from a device, it pauses the current execution statement and jumps to the handler for the interrupt via a lookup table.

Comment: An event is dad comes home and yells I am home.  A loop is you come down the stairs every minute to see if dad is home.  And just how would you you write a loop to see if the letter 'a' is pressed?

Comment: I researched what "john bledsoe" posted here about (Windows message processing loop) and found a very helpful youtube video named "C++ Win32 Lesson 2: The Message Loop" it sums it all up in a 3:32 min vid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between an event and a loop (which is called polling) is in performance and resource consumption.

In the loop-case (polling), the CPU is always active, checking the keyboard. This uses much energy. If many programs want to know about key presses and do the same thing, the whole PC is busy just checking whether a key is pressed or not.

Also note: you want to check for key presses every millisecond only. But how do you know that a millisecond is over? This will result in a loop like this:

```
long timeBefore = timer();
long timeAfter = timeBefore;
while (timeAfter - time < 1000) // 1000 us = 1 ms
{
    timeAfter = timer();
}
```

Having such a loop consumes 100% CPU time (1 core).

People have recognized this situation early and key presses and timer ticks are handled by hardware. The hardware triggers an interrupt. The interrupt is handled by the operating system and converted into an event. This applies to key presses as well as timer ticks (and other things).

That way, your program can go to sleep, the CPU can do something else and the operating system will wake up your program whenever the event that you specified occurs.

Note that this is a simplified description. The details are much more complex. If you want to know the details on Windows, read [Mark Russinovich's Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648735) (especially chapter 3). But be aware that I didn't fully understand this book even I read it the second time.

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone i understand now and i will "read mark russinovich's windows internals" to look deeper if need be.

Answer (score 2):

> how events truly work.

I would guess the code that handles keyboard events sits dormant.  When a *hardware* event occurs, the CPU loads a register with the address of the keyboard event handler and it runs.

There is no polling.

Answer (score 0):

you cant have a lot of loops in your application checking for multiple conditions and working async.
with events OperatingSystem listen for all messages(events)(its a real loop in the OS), then it passes the event you subscribed to with your application.